# :driver_opts is deprecated. Use :service with an instance of Selenium::WebDriver::Service instead

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

```
2019-06-19 15:44:43 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] :driver_opts is deprecated. Use :service with an instance of Selenium::WebDriver::Service instead.
Screenshot error, but continue to execute.
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
2019-06-19 15:44:43 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] :driver_opts is deprecated. Use :service with an instance of Selenium::WebDriver::Service instead.
2019-06-19 15:44:43 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] :driver_opts is deprecated. Use :service with an instance of Selenium::WebDriver::Service instead.
          visit in hook, after scenario +1s, @1s
2019-06-19 15:44:43 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] :driver_opts is deprecated. Use :service with an instance of Selenium::WebDriver::Service instead.
```

I've been using the below code snippet to init a session with old 'selenium-webdriver' v3.6.0 and got the above error:

***Updated on June 23rd.***

```
if Capybara.default_driver == :selenium
    Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
        # In the block, we build up an `options` hash to pass to
        #   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, options)
        # which in turn calls
        #   Selenium::WebDriver.for(options[:browser], options)

        browser = Configuration.fetch('browser.type', :firefox) 
        options = {
            browser: browser, # chrome
        }

        if Configuration.fetch('options.webdriver.use_hub', false)
            {...}
        elsif browser == :firefox
            {...}
        elsif browser == :chrome
            chrome_logpath = "../chromedriver.log"
            options[:service] = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Service.chrome(
                args: {
                    verbose: true,
                    log_path: chrome_logpath,
                }
            )
            chrome_options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
            chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent='QA Test'")
            chrome_options.add_option('w3c',false)
            options[:options] = chrome_options
        end
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, options)
    end
end
```

After bumped that gem to v3.142.0 then I got that error. Tracing back to the Selenium Webdriver Changelog in https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/CHANGES then i found the following description, which might break the current code 
3.141.592 (2019-04-18)

```
Chrome: 
Added support for instantiating service class directly and moved all driver executable configuration there (command-line arguments, port, etc.)
Passing driver_opts, driver_path and port to driver initializer is now deprecated 
so use Selenium::WebDriver::Service.chrome instead, 
which allows to customize executable behavior in similar way.
 Once initialized, this object can be passed as :service keyword 
during driver initialization. 
* Deprecated Chrome.driver_path= in favor of Service::Chrome.driver_path=
```

Googling for a while i found some results and workaround like using 'webdriver' gem but i don't like it that much.

So wonder if something that i can change my  snippet above to adapt with that selenium-webdriver ver 3.142.0 and onwards? I'm using Capybara v3.18.0 at the moment.

Thanks everyone,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not an error, it's a deprecation warning. It's telling you that you will need to change your code before selenium-webdriver v4.0 is released. If you feel you must update your code today it would be something like

```
elsif browser == :chrome

  options[:service] = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Service.chrome(
    args: {
      verbose: true,
      log_path: "../chromedriver.log",
    }
  )

  chrome_options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

  # add user agent to that class options
  chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent='QA Test'")
  options[:options] = chrome_options
end
```

The other stuff you show

```
Screenshot error, but continue to execute.
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

is something different and isn't coming from any of the code you're showing.

Comment: Agreed. this ```Screenshot error, but continue to execute.
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)``` was prompted since it used one of the args (log_path) to take a screenshot.

Comment: @DinhLuong I don’t fully understand what you mean by that comment, but if whatever gem/code you’re using is attempting to access the log_path setting through non-public APIs on selenium-webdriver then that gem or code is going to need to be updated

Comment: ```already started: #<URI::HTTP http://127.0.0.1:9565/> "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"```
After setting up as your suggestion, this error appears and looks like the session has been started (actually didn't have any up& running session in my local). Not sure if i need to change somewhere else in my codebase to adapt to this.

Comment: You're opening multiple sessions and I guess (because you don't show more code) that you're creating the Service object outside of the driver registration block. This means every session is trying to use the same Service instance - You need to create the Service object inside the driver registration block so each session gets its own copy.

Comment: Hi @Thomas Walpole, as i have updated my driver registration code snippet (in question content) , do you mind having a look at it? As i think it's still inside the driver registration block, isn't it ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DinhLuong Yes that is inside the driver registration block, which means a new Service object should be created for each session (not really sure why you have the `if Capybara.default_driver == :selenium` around it though) .  If you're still getting the "already started" error - then you should probably just go back to the deprecation warning version for now.   Either you're doing something weird with sessions or the way selenium-webdriver has implemented the Service class isn't going to work with Capybara when v4 releases.

Comment: Hi @Thomas Walpole The `Capybara.default_driver` was set from fetching the configuration like `Configuration['driver']` from the `configuration.yml` for some global configuration. So as i understand, that either should have reverted to the deprecation warning selenium-webdriver version or wait for newer version of Capybara which will somehow work with that Service class once v4 release, i guess  ? Cheers.

Comment: @DinhLuong The reason I don't understand the `if Capybara.default_driver == :selenium` around it is because even if that isn't true, there is no downside to registering the driver so the `if ...` is pointless - just register the driver.  Beyond that, if having the `::Selenium::WebDriver::Service.chrome` inside the driver registration block doesn't end up creating a new service for each session, then selenium 4 won't work with Capybara.  I'm guessing its more about how you're creating multiple sessions, but I can't be sure with the limited code shown.

Comment: hi @Thomas Walpole, thanks for looking at it. Actually, when i tried go back n forth between the older version of selenium-webdriver as 3.6.0 and the newer one 3.142.3 to compare what's the difference in both cases, found out with the older one, for the same driver registration block, only 1 session was created, while the newer one, there were multiple `chromedriver` session was created with different port, pid. The way i reproduced was just run the test scripts and interrupted it on the fly then checking the command `ps aux |grep chromedriver` in my machine.